# I cant ssh into my google cloud using console,gcloud or any

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

This is the response when i ssh through console
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.

This is the response when i ssh through gcloud
Waiting for SSH key to propagate. ssh: connect to host 35.185.185.41 port 22: Operation timed out ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

Please help me to solve this issue
Thanks

Comment: A timeout usually points to a firewall issue.

Comment: ya default-allow-ssh is already in allow mode in my Firewall rules of google cloud platform @ Gerald Schneider

Comment: i solved using this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759251/google-compute-engine-alternative-log-in-to-vm-instance-if-ssh-port-is-disable

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you might have done some misconfigurations in your instance, you can use the [interactive serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) to SSH into the instance. 
If you don't have the root password, you can use a script to set the root password as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash 
useradd -G sudo USERNAME
echo 'USERNAME:PASSWORD' | chpasswd
```

You can set the key metadata to 'startup-script' and the 'Value' will be the script.

Restart the instance and use the password you just setup to login in to the interactive console.

As caution, when the issue is solved, disable as "the interactive serial console does not support IP-based access restrictions such as IP whitelists"